# Add PHP with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add php with jquery. I understand that this is not possible due to the one being sever side and the other client side, but is there a workaround?

The php is generated from plugin in wordpress that will display random advertising banners.

Thank you.

[link to the table ( dev site )](http://dohne.thissideupmedia.com/sires-young/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var i=0;
jQuery('.foo-table > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
i++;
if (i%2==0) {
 jQuery(this).after("<tr><td colspan=0>Hello" <?php echo adrotate_group(1); ?>  "</td></tr>")     
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you used incorrect quotes

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    jQuery('.foo-table > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
        i++;
        if (i%2==0) {
            jQuery(this).after("<tr><td colspan=0>Hello <?php echo adrotate_group(1); ?></td></tr>")
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add php code in jquery using Wordpress CMS then you can use the `wp_localize_script` function, it will be beneficial if you need to add static value.

**Add the below code in your current active theme functions.php file.**

```
  function custom_load_scripts(){ 

    // Register the script
    wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

    // Localize the script with new data
    $translation_array = array(
        'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
        'a_value' => '10'
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

    // Enqueued script with localized data.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );

    }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_load_scripts');
```

In your **myscript.js** file use object_name.a_value to get the php value.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var acount = object_name.a_value;
   alert(acount);
});
```

But if you want some things dynamic then you need to use AJAX: To get ajax help [click Here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) .

For ajax action : [Click Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it like that. But instead of trying to call php like that, you can make an AJAX call which will return HTML for your ad which you will insert with JS wherever you need.
More on AJAX in Wordpress [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) or in [old codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)